# Compare value of a row with multiple rows in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's imagine I have two tables of orders which I want to compare to eachother.

```
orders {
   id int, 
   price money
}

ordereditems {
   orderid int, 
   itemid int,
   price money
}
```

where **orders.id = ordereditems.orderid**

Naturally, this is a bad design since both tables don't need a price. However, how can I design a query to find out what rows in orders has a price, which mismatches with the sum  of the pricecolumn in ordereditems?

Comment: try using left join on orders.id = ordereditems.orderid and do the comparison or what ever calculation u need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right:

```
SELECT * FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN OrderedItems ei
ON o.Price = ei.Price WHERE ei.Price is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.price,
       b.price,
       CASE
         WHEN a.price = b.price THEN 'PRICE MATCHED'
         ELSE 'PRICE NOT MATCHED'
       END AS RESULT
FROM   orders a
       INNER JOIN ordereditems b
               ON a.id = b.orderid
                  AND a.price IS NOT NULL
```

--orders has a price, which mismatches with the sum of the pricecolumn in ordereditems

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.price,
       b.total_price,
       CASE
         WHEN a.price = b.total_price THEN 'PRICE MATCHED'
         ELSE 'PRICE NOT MATCHED'
       END AS RESULT
FROM   orders a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT orderid,
                          Sum(price) AS total_price
                   FROM   ordereditems
                   GROUP  BY orderid) b
               ON a.id = b.orderid
                  AND a.price IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This is working good, as long as there is only one orderitem per order. If one order contains two items, it doesn't work :(

Comment: Calculate the price of all items in OrderedItems table for an orderid. USE GROUPBY.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to sum a value from two columns with prefer an existing one:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(o.price, oi.price)) as price -- reorder columns for prefer
FROM orders o INNER JOIN -- if you are missing some rows use FULL JOIN
ordereditems oi ON oi.id = o.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below query to get order id's with mismatched price

```
SELECT o.id,MAX(o.price) AS price
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN ordereditems oi
ON o.id=oi.orderid
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING SUM(oi.price)<>MAX(o.price)
```